# I made reused my React Element twice, the second doesn't respond to clicks

Tags: reactjs

I can't seem to reuse my reusable React Dropdown I made. [image: gif] heres a gif.

I've tried setting different styles with random numbers as the values, I've tried using IDs. Adding classes etc.

Here's the React element (tsx)

https://hasteb.in/ilohiyef.kotlin

Here's the styles for it

https://hasteb.in/cimiyuda.yaml

And here's the code I used in the other file (the faulty one)

https://hasteb.in/ohocajal.xml

And here's the working dropdown

https://hasteb.in/etobapib.xml

Comment: Have you tried console logging the stuff on the onClick to see what's happening? I'm curious what the parentRef is coming up as.

Comment: Also, move your click event outside of the render() like ```clickEvent = () => { whatever }``` then called in the render function as ```this.clickEvent```

Comment: @Mark Alright so I've moved the clickEvent out of the render(), here's the console logging in the onClick for parentRef, https://i.imgur.com/oWzUUb4.gifv https://i.imgur.com/TYFUgtk.png